# How to Configure WSO2 APIM to use Plain HTTP Internally

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are upgrading from 2.6 to 4.2.  We are using ansible to do manage the installation/deployment.  We have a problem: while it works on our (devs) local VMs, on the server while the UI, API registration, etc all work it fails to call any back-end APIs.  We can see that what is timing out is an internal call within WSO2 to itself.  The WSO2 logs show the log extract below while a packet capture shows a request from a port on the machine  where the APIM is running to port 8243 on the same machine is timing out - and nothing is leaving the machine to try and actually call the back-end (which is on a different server - we can manually call the backend from the WSO2 machine without problem).

We think it might be a certificate issue.  Trying to call that port ourselves results in a certificate error since it's presenting the self-signed cert. Our setup is a single-node WSO2 APIM behind a reverse proxy (we use Apache HTTPD for the reverse proxy) so we could use plain HTTP for the calls from the proxy to WSO2 and within WSO2 (since no such calls will leave that machine). However, I can't see how to configure that. Can anyone help?  If that isn't possible, how can we supply our SSL certs to WSO2 so it uses a valid cert?  The closest I can find to either in the WSO2 docs is [how t control which TLS ciphers are allowed](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-transport-level-security/) but maybe I am missing something.

If we are on totally the wrong track, and anyone has any other ideas, then any suggestions very welcome.  The log extract is

```
TID: [] [] [2023-05-16 10:42:38,078] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - http-incoming-36: Timeout
TID: [] [] [2023-05-16 10:42:38,078]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
TID: [] [] [2023-05-16 10:42:38,078]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - STATE_DESCRIPTION = Socket Timeout occurred after accepting the request headers and the request body, INTERNAL_STATE = REQUEST_DONE, DIRECTION = REQUEST, CAUSE_OF_ERROR = Connection between the client and the EI timeouts, HTTP_URL = /integrations/scim/carcwso2/v1/integrations/scim/v2/Users/apiuser, HTTP_METHOD = GET, SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 180000, CLIENT_ADDRESS = /10.0.100.60:33982, CONNECTION http-incoming-36 Correlation ID : 1b58ec31-3bbd-4e5e-a197-d18f67424aef
TID: [] [] [2023-05-16 10:42:38,078] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.connections.SourceConnections} - Shutting down connection forcefully http-incoming-36
TID: [] [] [2023-05-16 10:42:38,078] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection} - http-incoming-36: Shutdown connection
TID: [] [] [2023-05-16 10:42:38,078] DEBUG {org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession} - I/O session http-incoming-36-36 10.0.100.60:8243<->10.0.100.60:33982[ACTIVE][:r][ACTIVE][][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0]: Shutdown
TID: [] [] [2023-05-16 10:42:38,078] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - http-incoming-36: Closed
TID: [] [] [2023-05-16 10:42:38,078] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - http-incoming-36: Keep-Alive connection was closed:  Remote Address : null
TID: [] [] [2023-05-16 10:42:38,078] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.connections.SourceConnections} - Shutting down connection forcefully http-incoming-36
TID: [] [] [2023-05-16 10:42:38,078] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection} - http-incoming-36: Shutdown connection
TID: [] [] [2023-05-16 10:42:38,079] DEBUG {org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession} - I/O session http-incoming-36-36 [CLOSED][][CLOSED][][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0]: Shutdown
TID: [] [] [2023-05-16 10:42:38,200] DEBUG {org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundEventManager} - [ Sequence: 3337 ] SAFE_ZONE_DECLARE_EVENT' published to Disruptor
```

Comment: Why do you say it's an SSL issue? This seems like a connection issue, probably a firewall rule blocking the call. Just to confirm this happens when you invoke an API? If so, have you specified default versions for these APIs? (That's the only time APIM will call itself) Also can you enable https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/using-wire-logs/ and share the logs.

Comment: Also, what happens if you `telnet 10.0.100.60 8243` from within the APIM server?

Comment: We have tried with the local firewall disabled and it's all within the same machine.  If we try to cUrl we get the cert error, so that was our next step: to get rid of that.  But we have now found the underlying issues and don't need to anymore we think

Answer (score 0):

We have (we think) found the underlying problem.  We therefore do not need to change the SSL configuration and this question is now moot.  It was not a difference in the hosting environment but in the configuration.  Namely that the WSO2 admin user (in the environment we were using to test on the real servers) included a # in the password and we therefore fell foul of https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/12186

If we change the password to something with any # characters it seems to work.  We will continue to test.